# Save HTML Form to PDF or Docx using Angular 4

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular

I'm currently running Angular 4 with Node and MySQL. I have a form, that when submitted, should open a Save As.. prompt so that the entered contents of the form will be saved to a PDF or Word Doc.

I've tried using htmlDox and saveAs but I keep getting error after error. Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to make my own PDF.

**component.ts**

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
...
...
constructor() {
  pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs; 
}
...
...

this.makePdf().then(function(results) {
  pdf = results;
  ///
  //You can now send your doc to the api and save it do a database.
  ///
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});


makePdf():Promise<any> {
  this.docDefinition =  { 
    content: [ ... ]
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    pdfMake.createPdf(this.docDefinition).getBase64(function(buffer) {
      resolve(buffer);
    });
  });
}
```

I had to use a promise becuase generating the document was taking too long. This way you wait for the document to finish be generated and can move on with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Jspdf is a popular library to use in javascript application. Try it.